# Seleccionar un option de forma dinamica angular

Tags: angularjs

Hola a todos gracias por vuestra respuesta y el tiempo dedicado.

Tengo otra duda es posible con angular poner un option seleccionado de forma dinámica porque tengo que lograr eso. En el código html tengo esto donde keysSecurityTypes es un array que se encuentra en un controlador con los valores que quiero mostrar. Pero la cosa es que tengo qe inicializar los options con un valor por defecto que puede variar segun lo que me llega desde una base de datos que corresponde a los mismos valores del keysSecurityTypes pero solo un valor según lo que me venga de la base de datos tengo qe mostrar los valores del array keysSecurityTypes y ademas poner en el option un valor por defecto que puede cambiar colocando el select no me funcionaria porque seria siempre para el mismo elemento y no de forma dinámica con angular. Ese valor solo es cargado una sola vez cuando se muestran los option pero como depende de la base de datos si ese valor cambia debería cambiar el valor en el option.

en el controlador

```
public keysSecurityTypes : Array<string> = new Array("WPA2", "WPA", "WPA/WPA2");
public valorSeleccionadoPorDefecto : string; // este valor puede cambiar y indica cual es el elemento del array que debe aparecer seleccionado en el option del html
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="securityType" ng change="wifi.selectedSecurityType(securityType)">
               <option ng-repeat="types in wifi.keysSecurityTypes">{{types}}</option>
             </select>
```

Gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="keysSecurityTypes=[{is:'false',name:'WPA'},{is:'false', name: 'WPA2'},{is: 'false', name: 'WPA/WPA2'}]">
    <select ng-model="securityType" ng-init="securityType = 'true'">
        <option ng-repeat="option in keysSecurityTypes" value="{{option.is}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Tienes que cambiar **keysSecurityTypes** a un objeto tal como eso (Lo hago en JS para su mejor comprensión)

```
var keysSecurity = [
    {is: 'true', name: 'WPA'},
    {is: 'false', name: 'WPA2'},
    {is: 'false', name: 'WPA/WPA2'},
];
```

Answer (score 1):

No debes usar `ng-repeat` para hacer las opciones de tu `select`, usa `ng-options` que está diseñado para eso

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('WifiCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.wifi = {
      keysSecurityTypes: ['WPA2', 'WPA', 'WPA/WPA2'],
      selected: ''
    }

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.wifi.selected = 'WPA/WPA2';
    }, 3000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="WifiCtrl">
  <p>Simulando llamada ajax</p>
  <p>Espere unos segundos para que el valor se actualice</p>
  <select ng-options="type for type in wifi.keysSecurityTypes" ng-model="wifi.selected"></select>
</div>
```

En el ejemplo el valor seleccionado se actualiza al cabo de unos segundos al igual que si hubiera llegado del servidor y para actualizar el valor seleccionado solo tuve que cambiar el valor de `ng-model`. Además `ng-repeat` te crea una nuevo `$scope` por cada elemento `option` por lo que tiene peor desempeño que `ng-options` para crear elementos de un select.